# Load ASP.NET Core plugins and their dependencies

Tags: c#, plugin, asp.net-core

I'd like one of my RESTful services to support plugins. Currently it uses references hardwired at compile-time.

The [Application Parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts) seem to be THE solution so I gave it a try and created a small proof-of-concept service.

It loads plugins located in the `ext` subdirectory. Each plugin is located in its own subdirectory named after the plugin itself and it may contain its own dependencies e.g.:

```
ext\PluginTest.HalloWord\PluginTest.HalloWorld.dll
ext\PluginTest.HalloWord\PluginTest.HalloWorldHelper.dll
```

I implemented it by loading plugins with the `ConfigureApplicationPartManager` and later if plugin dependencies are requested I try to resolve them in the plugin's directory with the `AssemblyResolve` event handler. Additionaly each assembly can also contain embedded views. The Razor view engine is able to find them via `EmbeddedFileProvider` for each loaded plugin.

```
public class Startup
{
    private const string PluginsDirectoryName = "ext";

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        HostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var pluginName = e.RequestingAssembly.GetName().Name;

            // Extract dependency name from the full assembly name:
            // PluginTest.HalloWorldHelper, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null
            var pluginDependencyName = e.Name.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();

            var pluginDependencyFullName = 
                Path.Combine(
                    HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, 
                    PluginsDirectoryName, 
                    pluginName, 
                    $"{pluginDependencyName}.dll"
                );

            return
                File.Exists(pluginDependencyFullName)
                    ? Assembly.LoadFile(pluginDependencyFullName)
                    : null;
        };

        var pluginAssemblies = 
            GetPluginAssemblies(HostingEnvironment)
                .ToList();

        services
            .AddMvc()
            .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
            {
                foreach (var pluginAssembly in pluginAssemblies)
                {
                    apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(pluginAssembly));
                }
            });

        // Views are embeded in plugins so add a resolver so that the Razor view engine can find them.
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
            foreach (var pluginAssembly in pluginAssemblies)
            {
                options
                    .FileProviders
                    .Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(pluginAssembly));
            }                
        });
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetPluginAssemblies(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        var pluginDirectoryName = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, PluginsDirectoryName);

        if (!Directory.Exists(pluginDirectoryName))
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var pluginDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(pluginDirectoryName);
        foreach (var pluginDirectory in pluginDirectories)
        {
            var pluginFullName =
                Path.Combine(
                    hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath,
                    pluginDirectory,
                    $"{Path.GetFileName(pluginDirectory)}.dll"
                );

            if (File.Exists(pluginFullName))
            {
                yield return Assembly.LoadFile(pluginFullName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My PoC works, loads plugins, their dependencies and correctly executes controllers that were loaded dynamically.

I was wondering whether there is anything about this simple solution that could be done better?

Comment: Apart from converting the service configuration to extension methods, There is not much else I would change in the current code based on my initial look at it. I'm still reviewing it over though so I may come up with something.

Comment: missing where `_hostingEnvironment` is coming from, but assuming that was a typo while copying over the code?

Comment: Does `AddMvc` call `AddOptions` internally? Not seeing where that is enabled as well.

Comment: @Nkosi yes, sorry, it was a copy/pase error, it should be the property. I mistakenly copied code from another solution where I use fields instead of properties :-/ about `AddOptions` - I don't think I'm using this one... or do you mean this `services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>`? I didn't have to activate anything else for this to work. It's the exact code I'm using. No `AddOptions` anywhere.

Comment: ok, drafting up some refactors based on some repeated code.

Comment: Am doing the same thing but I want to give my plugins a way to load and unload the plug-in from a ui where you able to do this much in same way nopcomerce.  I’ll no I will need to track somehow the list of loaded assemblies. But am not sure how to unload them.  Also could you plz show an example of how your describing you plug-in classes. Ur if your using Iplugin interface or some other method

Comment: @DavidBuckley they broke plugins in .net-core-3 so I threw them away (the framework was unable to find views) :-| Since then I didn't try it again. I hope they've fixed it. net-5.

Comment: @t3chb0t can you tell me what I should search for in the docs to tell lif their fixed or not. Strange that nopcomerce has plugins working in their artecheture for .net core 3

Comment: @DavidBuckley they might have found a workaround or a later updated fixed it. The early version gave me view paths errors all the time that never came in .net-core-2, only after switching to .net-core-3. This is the error: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14374 - There might be more of such tickets. I didn't follow it so I cannot tell you what is the current behaviour but it's exactly the same issue that I experienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from converting the service configuration to extension methods, There is not much else I would change in the current code.

There is repeated code that can be refactored out into their own concerns.

```
public static class PluginConfigurationExtensions {

    public IServiceCollection AddMvcPlugins(IServiceCollection services, string pluginsRootPath) {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ConfigureAssemblyResolve(pluginsRootPath);

        var pluginAssemblies = GetPluginAssemblies(pluginsRootPath).ToList();

        // Setup options with DI
        services.AddOptions();

        services
            .AddMvc()
            .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm => {
                foreach (var pluginAssembly in pluginAssemblies) {
                    apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(pluginAssembly));
                }
            });

        // Views are embedded in plugins so add a resolver so that the Razor view engine can find them.
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(_ => {
            foreach (var pluginAssembly in pluginAssemblies) {
                _
                    .FileProviders
                    .Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(pluginAssembly));
            }                
        });
        return services;
    }

    private static void ConfigureAssemblyResolve(this AppDomain appDomain, string pluginsRootPath) {
        appDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) => {
            var pluginName = e.RequestingAssembly.GetName().Name;

            // Extract dependency name from the full assembly name:
            // PluginTest.HalloWorldHelper, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null
            var pluginDependencyName = e.Name.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();

            var pluginDependencyFullName = Path.Combine(
                    pluginsRootPath,
                    pluginName,
                    $"{pluginDependencyName}.dll"
                );

            return
                File.Exists(pluginDependencyFullName)
                    ? Assembly.LoadFile(pluginDependencyFullName)
                    : null;
        };
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetPluginAssemblies(string pluginsRootPath) {
        if (!Directory.Exists(pluginsRootPath)) {
            yield break;
        }

        var pluginDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(pluginsRootPath);
        foreach (var pluginDirectory in pluginDirectories) {
            var pluginFullName =
                Path.Combine(
                    pluginsRootPath,
                    $"{Path.GetFileName(pluginDirectory)}.dll"
                );

            if (File.Exists(pluginFullName)) {
                yield return Assembly.LoadFile(pluginFullName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This reduces the `ConfigureServices` to

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    var pluginsRootPath = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, PluginsDirectoryName);    

    services.AddMvcPlugins(pluginsRootPath);

    //...
}
```

You could consider putting the `PluginsDirectoryName` in the `appsetting.json` and extracting it via `IOptions` instead of hard-coding it in `Startup`.

Comment: This looks good and I like the new names of some of the variables.

Comment: Ended up going with the one line config. Less room for error.

Comment: I love asp.net-core. You can override virtually everything. If something doesn't work the way you'd like it to... there is for sure an interface you can use to implement it your way ;-D

Comment: Well one of the biggest selling points of core was its modularity which allowed more extensibility.

Answer (score 1):

I followed most of [@Nkosi](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189944/59161) suggestions and reorganized the code for registering plugins.

---

I changed the main extension to work on the `IMvcBuilder` to avoid calling `AddMvc` inside it.

This gives me access to the `IMvcBuilder.Services` property that can be used to get other services that this exension requires. This way it's not necessary to pass any other arguments to it. The two directory names are now stored in the `appsettings.json` file.

I also slightly changed how the extensions are loaded because I didn't like the embedded views. I prefer to be able to change the *Text/HTML* without deploying a new `*.dll`. This means that views are resolved now from the `src\Views` directory instead.

The new directory structure is:

```
\ext
    \PluginX
        \bin
            PluginX.dll
        \src
            \Views
                Index.cshtml
```

*(The Razor view engine knows about the `src` folder because I override the resolution with a custom `IViewLocationExpander`.)*

```
public static class MvcBuilderPluginExtensions
{
    // Adds plugins located in \{Root}\Plugin\{Binary}\Plugin.dll
    // Example: \ext\Plugin\bin\Plugin.dll    
    public static IMvcBuilder AddPlugins(this IMvcBuilder mvc)
    {
        var serviceProvider = mvc.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var configuration = serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        var hostingEnvironment = serviceProvider.GetService<IHostingEnvironment>();
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILoggerFactory>().CreateLogger<Startup>();

        var pluginsRootPath = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, configuration["PluginDirectory:Root"]);
        var pluginAssemblies = GetPluginAssemblies(pluginsRootPath, configuration["PluginDirectory:Binary"]).ToList();

        logger.Log(Abstraction.Layer.Infrastructure().Data().Variable(new { pluginAssemblies = pluginAssemblies.Select(x => x.FullName) }));

        mvc
            .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
            {
                foreach (var pluginAssembly in pluginAssemblies)
                {
                    logger.Log(Abstraction.Layer.Infrastructure().Data().Object(new { pluginAssembly = new { pluginAssembly.FullName } }));
                    apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(pluginAssembly));
                }
            });

        mvc
            .Services
            .ConfigureRazorViewEngine(hostingEnvironment, pluginAssemblies, pluginsRootPath);

        ConfigureAssemblyResolve(logger, pluginsRootPath, configuration["PluginDirectory:Binary"]);

        return mvc;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetPluginAssemblies(string pluginsRootPath, string binDirectoryName)
    {
        if (!Directory.Exists(pluginsRootPath))
        {
            yield break;
        }

        var pluginDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(pluginsRootPath);
        foreach (var pluginDirectory in pluginDirectories)
        {
            // C:\..\ext\Plugin\bin\Plugin.dll
            var pluginFullName =
                Path.Combine(
                    pluginDirectory,
                    binDirectoryName,
                    $"{Path.GetFileName(pluginDirectory)}.dll"
                );

            if (File.Exists(pluginFullName))
            {
                yield return Assembly.LoadFile(pluginFullName);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void ConfigureAssemblyResolve(ILogger logger, string pluginsRootPath, string binDirectoryName)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // Extract dependency name from the full assembly name:
            // FooPlugin.FooClass, Version = 1.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null
            var pluginDependencyName = e.Name.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();

            // C:\..\ext\Plugin\bin\PluginDependency.dll
            var pluginDependencyFullName =
                Path.Combine(
                    pluginsRootPath,
                    pluginDependencyName,
                    binDirectoryName,
                    $"{pluginDependencyName}.dll"
                );

            logger.Log(Abstraction.Layer.Infrastructure().Data().Variable(new { pluginDependencyFullName }));

            return
                File.Exists(pluginDependencyFullName)
                    ? Assembly.LoadFile(pluginDependencyFullName)
                    : null;
        };
    }

    // Adds plugin directory to Razor view engine so that it can resolve plugin's views e.g. \ext\Plugin
    private static void ConfigureRazorViewEngine(this IServiceCollection services, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment, IEnumerable<Assembly> pluginAssemblies, string pluginsRootPath)
    {
        services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
        {
            foreach (var pluginAssembly in pluginAssemblies)
            {
                var pluginRootPath =
                    Path.Combine(
                        pluginsRootPath,
                        pluginAssembly.GetName().Name
                    );

                options
                    .FileProviders
                    .Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(pluginRootPath));
            }

            // Extension development does not use plugins so we have to look for it in the current directory parent 
            // because the service is "installed" as a submodule which is a subdirectory.
            if (hostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment("Extension"))
            {
                // ContentRootPath is the path of the *.csproj, we have to go back two levels to reach the extension directory.
                var extensionDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath).Parent?.Parent;

                if (extensionDirectory is null)
                {
                    throw new DirectoryNotFoundException("Could not find extension directory.");
                }

                options
                    .FileProviders
                    .Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(extensionDirectory.FullName, extensionDirectory.Name)));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Registering the plugin engine has now become a one-liner:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    //..

    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddPlugins();

    //..
}
```

Comment: t3chb0t this solution seems really cool. I tried to use your framework but without success. I wonder if you have a github example or simular that gives an overview over the structure? Plugins seems to load, but are not published to the router.

Comment: Also the Abstraction.Layer.Infrastructure().Data() variables are unknowns, so it doesn't show what plugin was loaded.

Comment: @Large yes, it's on GitHub. You can find the latest version [here](https://github.com/he-dev/mailr/blob/master/Mailr/src/Mvc/PluginExtensions.cs) - let me know if you have any questions ;-)

Comment: thank you for a very quick reply :) I will check out the mailr repro

Comment: @Large could you load the plugin successfully?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani plugin loading works only with `net47`. I upgraded it to `netcoreapp2.2` and it was completely broken. It could not find the views anymore (the controllers were fine and they were calling the correct view but namespaces were broken and thus views too). This is expected to be fixed in .net-core-3. So only precompiled `*.View.dll` work if you use core.

Comment: @t3chb0t yes, I'm using core, the Views loaded successfully, thanks to the `services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions> ...`, but the Controllers in plugin project doesn't work/load. there is no error, and also the `ConfigureApplicationPartManager` part doesn't do anything for me, I mean I can omit this part and still get same result.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani yup, this is very tricky and I couldn't make it work with net-core :( I  currently use plugin projects referenced in the main project and hope they will fix it in the next version because the whole point of this tool was to not use precompiled views so that they can be modified without deploing the app but unfortunately it's broken.

Comment: @t3chb0t did you check [this](https://github.com/simplcommerce/SimplCommerce) project? and [this one](https://github.com/thiennn/trymodular)

Comment: @MehdiDehghani I will. They are new to me. Thanks for the links! ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t you're welcome, please let me know if you find anything helpful :p